# How to calculate the power associated with jet creation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Good day.

I am currently trying to understand what is the power required to create/maintain a jet flow.

The problem is:

- The jet leaves a surface in its normal direction from a plenum.
- The jet has a velocity of $U_j$.
- The surface mentioned above has a periodic prescribed velocity, $\dot{y}(t)$.
- The jet is not responsible (does not contribute with thrust) for the surface motion.

**Question:** What is the power required to create this jet?

***What has been tried so far:***

- $P=Tv= \dfrac{1}{2}\rho A U_j^3$
- $P=Tv= \dfrac{1}{2}\rho A U_j^2\dot{y}(t)$
- $P=Tv= \dfrac{1}{2}\rho A (U_j+\dot{y}(t))^2\dot{y}(t)$
- $P=Tv= \dfrac{1}{2}\rho A (U_j+\dot{y}(t))^3$

Best regards,

Emanuel Camacho